# foreground and background color in Material UI Theme

Tags: css, material-ui, themes

How to set 1 color for Card and a different color for Paper, in the Material UI Theme, that works in both dark and light mode

My App is a list of Cards (with padding) on top of a Paper background. By default the Paper and Card get the same color which seems wrong to me. I would like the colors to be slightly different so that the Cards stand out from the Paper a bit better.

What is the best way to setup the Theme to get this behaviour?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
export const MyTheme = {
  ...
  
  overrides: {
    MuiPaper: {  
      root: {
        color: '#fff',      
        backgroundColor: '#EF476F', 
      },
    },
    MuiCard: {
      root: {
        color: '#fff',      
        backgroundColor: '#1181b2', 
      },
    },
  },
}
```